# DirectAdmin auto backup script

Tags: php, sql, cron

How to create simple DirectAdmin(Unix) auto backup script just for DB(not the files, the cron jobs, DNS zones, email accounts, etc.) backup only?

Script should only zip the DB SQL file and send to e-mail or save to the server.